# Cisco Packet Tracer error "Invalid IP for this subnet mask entered"

Tags: networking, subnet

im using cisco packet tracer configuring pc ip and this error came out "Invalid IP for this subnet mask entered"

[image]

Comment: Your *Subnet mask* field is empty.

Comment: If you found a solution, please consider sharing it with us, so it can help others. Just post an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You did not enter anything in the fields IP Address and Subnet Mask. I think, you should enter valid values in these fields.